# 2 regression models giving same performance

Tags: python, regression, pytorch, svr, inceptionresnetv2

I have 2 regression models (1 is deeplearning based) and another is SVR both trained on the embeddings obtained from the last FC layer of ResNet50. Output variables are min-max normalized to get in the range of 0-1 (this improves the results overall of the model), but after that both the model's performance (test MSE) is the same +- 100 points. What could be an explanation for this?